# Service Worker registers but doesn't cache

Tags: caching, vuejs2, service-worker, workbox

I'm new to service workers and I'm running into an issue with my implementation. My goal is to create a runtime cache for images and videos. I've looked at the [workbox implementation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/serving-cached-audio-and-video/) but it hasn't worked for me. I see that my service worker successfully registers at the top-level scope of my app but for some reason, it seems like some of the code in my service worker file doesn't get executed. The main issue is that the event listeners from my service worker don't seem to get called (including `registerRoute`), and therefore, the Cache doesn't ever get created.

I'm not sure if this is related to the issue I'm having but when I look at the console messages, it seems like the code from `sw.js` may be run prior to the service worker registration:
[console messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADRDO.png)

I've been stuck on this problem for a while so I would appreciate some help if anyone has run into this issue, thanks!

```js
// main.js (in a Vue 2 app)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(`/sw.js`)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Service worker registered!");
          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
            registration.update();
            console.log('Service Worker: ready');
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn("Error registering service worker:");
          console.warn(error);
        });
    }
  });
}
```

```js
// sw.js
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { CacheFirst } from "workbox-strategies";
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from "workbox-cacheable-response";
import { RangeRequestsPlugin } from "workbox-range-requests";
import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";

const CACHE_PREFIX = "background-slideshow-cache";
const CACHE_VERSION = "v1";
const CACHE_RUNTIME = "runtime";
const BACKGROUND_SLIDESHOW_CACHE = `${CACHE_PREFIX}-${CACHE_RUNTIME}-${CACHE_VERSION}`;

clientsClaim();

const addToCache = async (url) => {
  const cache = await caches.open(BACKGROUND_SLIDESHOW_CACHE);
  if (!(await cache.match(url))) {
    await cache.add(url);
  }
};

const cacheFirstStrategy = new CacheFirst({
  cacheName: BACKGROUND_SLIDESHOW_CACHE,
  plugins: [
    new CacheableResponsePlugin({
      statuses: [200],
    }),
    new RangeRequestsPlugin(),
  ],
});

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.message) {
    if (event.data.message === "SKIP_WAITING") {
      self.skipWaiting();
    }
  }
});

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log('Service worker: fetch event', event);
})

console.log("Service Worker: in file");

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => {
    const { destination } = request;
    console.log("Service Worker:", "request", request);
    return destination === "video" || destination === "image";
  },
  ({ event, request }) => {
    // console.log("Service Worker: in the 2nd param", event, request);
    event.respondWith(async () => {
      await addToCache(request.url);
      return cacheFirstStrategy.handle({ request });
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of debugging, I realized that the minification of sw.js at build time was the reason this code wasn't able to execute. I decided to use `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` in my webpack config and this solved the issue!